# Simple Injector Register Concrete Type with Lifestyle

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am looking for a way that I can register a concrete type with a specified Lifestyle, essentially something like the following.

```
public void SomeFunction( Type concrete, Lifestyle lifestyle ) =>
    container.Register( concrete, lifestyle );
```

Comment: needs more info

Comment: I've already provided a code sample of what I'm looking to do, there is no matching signature in SimpleInjector. I can't really provide more info unless you can clarify what you need more info about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to making a single one-to-one mapping in Simple Injector, there is practically just one method:

```
Container.Register(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, Lifestyle lifestyle);
```

All other methods are just convenient overloads or 'shortcuts' to this method. The following method for instance:

```
Container.Register<TService, TImplementation>(Lifestyle)
```

Eventually falls back to the non-generic overload by calling `Register(typeof(TService), typeof(TImplementation), lifestyle)`.

The same holds for overloads that don't take in a `Lifestyle`:

```
Container.Register<TService, TImplementation>()
```

They just forward the call by supplying the determined lifestyle for the given implementation type, which is -under default configuration- is the transient lifestyle: `Register<TService, TImpementation>(Lifestyle.Transient)`.

And there are multiple overloads that allow a shortcut registration for concrete types, such as:

```
Container.Register<TConcrete>()
```

This method forwards the call to `Register<TConcrete, TConcrete>()`. In other words, `TConcrete` is both supplied for `TService` and `TImplementation`. So eventually, this call ends up as `Register(typeof(TConcrete), typeof(TConcrete), Lifestyle.Transient)`.

So, long story short, the following methods allow you to register a concrete type with a lifestyle:

```
Register<TConcrete>(Lifestyle.Scoped)
Register<TConcrete, TConcrete>(Lifestyle.Scoped)
Register(typeof(Concrete), typeof(Concrete), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 container.Register<SomeConcreteType,SomeConcreteType>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

The lifestyle is one of these: Transient, Scoped or Singleton

Comment: You might want to look at the question again. The code sample is using a Type not Generics.