# How to register a concrete object that uses an interface with Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

In the following code, the `HomeController` receives a `ValueObject` whose state `someValue` changes so often in the DB. The state is retrieved in the constructor.

How can I register the `HomeController` in the container using `IHomeController` so whenever the `HomeController` is accessed, a new `ValueObject` is created as well as it's state is updated as well?

```
public class HomeController()
{
    public HomeController(ValueObject value)
    {
    }
}

public class ValueObject()
{
    public someValues { get; private set; }

    public ValueObject(IValueRepository repository)
    {
        // The someValue changes very often in the system
        someValue = repository.GetSomeValues();
    }
}
```

Comment: update your example. the code snippet does not reflect the content of the question.

Comment: You don't need `IHomeController` for this. You need to use proper DI container and register `ValueObject` and `ValueRepository` with lifetime `PerRequest`. That will create new instance of them for every request and executing method on them will get you new state for every request. I would also recommend to have HomeController dependent on the repository and let repository return the object of `ValueObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
container.Register<HomeController>();
container.Register<ValueObject>();
container.Register<IValueRepository, SqlValueRepository>();
```

From a DI perspective, your `ValueObject` is troublesome, because it calls its dependencies in its constructor. Injection constructors however, [should be simple and reliable](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

So if your intention is to cache the `SomeValues`, a better design is to use a decorator. For instance

```
public class CachingValueRepositoryDecorator : IValueRepository
{
    private readonly Lazy<SomeValues> values;

    public CachingValueRepositoryDecorator(IValueRepository decoratee)
    { 
        this.values = new Lazy<SomeValues>(decoratee.GetSomeValues);
    }

    public SomeValues GetSomeValues() => this.values.Value;
}
```

Such decorator allows you to remove the need to have a `ValueObject` in the `HomeController` which can simply look as follows:

```
public class HomeController
{
    public HomeController(IValueRepository repository)
    {
    }
}
```

This can be registered as follows:

```
container.Register<HomeController>();
container.Register<IValueRepository, SqlValueRepository>();
container.RegisterDecorator<IValueRepository, CachingValueRepositoryDecorator>();
```

Comment: in context of SI, where can one find more information on what this pattern is doing  `container.Register<HomeController>()` vs this pattern that I see in documentation: `containter.Register<Interface, Class>()`. I am trying to understand more on the significance/relevance/advantage of such a pattern over the other one. thanks!
P.S: nvm found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499627/simple-injector-register-concrete-type-with-lifestyle

Comment: There is not really information very specifically on the comparision; I think [this page](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/using.html) comes the closest. But which registration to pick, simply depends on what you need to resolve. If you need to resolve/inject the concrete type, you need `Register<Concrete>`. If, however, you want to resolve or inject the interface, you need `Register<Interface, Concrete>`. That's about it.

Comment: thanks Steven for taking out the time to share the relevant documentation